# Writing a Python program that takes a number from the user and prints its digits from left to right

Tags: python

I have to write a program that takes a number from the user and prints its digits from left to right. (if the user gives `32768`, then the output should be `3 2 7 6 8`).

I wrote this code and the first half counts the digits and 2nd half separates the digits and prints them. Separately these two blocks of codes work (like if you give the value of count and n in the 2nd one it works) but together it's not working (ಥ﹏ಥ) the output shows 0 0 0 0 0

```
count=0
while n>0:
  count=count+1
  n=n//10

x=10**(count-1)
for a in range(1,count+1,1):
   y=int(n//x)
   n=n%x
   x=x/10

   print(y,end=" ")
```

Comment: Explain "not working". What happens, what should happen? Show an error message (if any) completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Your first loop modifies `n`, and then your second loop expects that `n` has its original value.  Make a copy of `n`, and then use one in the first loop and the other in the second.

Comment: `print(" ".join(str(n)))`

Comment: Assuming this is a homework question: have you recently learned about a thing called "recursion"?

Comment: noo I don't know what "recursion" is (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Comment: No worries, it doesn't need recursion, just could have been a training exercise for it.

Comment: assuming n is the variable having the integer print(n.replace('', ' '))

Comment: What would the output look like if the input is a negative number?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do:

```py
# take user input 
n = int(input())
print(' '.join(str(n)))
```

input:

```
32768
```

output:

```
3 2 7 6 8
```

Comment: I have to take the input as an integer (ಥ﹏ಥ)

Comment: yes, you can take int input. the variable `n` above is `int` only

Comment: OH RIGHT but we haven't been taught this ".join.str()" thing yet in our class so I don't know if I'm allowed to use it. But thank you anyway

Comment: @Rodoshi What have you been taught?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take an integer from the user (input). You're not allowed to use str.join().

Therefore:

```
n = int(input())

d = [] if n > 0 else [0]

while n > 0:
    d.insert(0, n % 10)
    n //= 10

print(*d)
```

**Console:**

```
3456
3 4 5 6
```

**Note:**

This won't work for negative numbers

Answer (score 0):

Isue with your code lies **in the second half** where you're trying to separate the digits and print them. The problem is that you're modifying the value of n within the loop, which **leads to incorrect results**.

**Try modyfing it like that:**

```
count = 0
original_n = n  # Store the original value of n

while n > 0:
    count += 1
    n //= 10

x = 10**(count-1)
n = original_n  # Reset n to the original value

for _ in range(1, count+1, 1):
    y = n // x
    n %= x
    x //= 10

    print(y, end=" ")
```

- `original_n` is used to keep track of the original value of `n`, while `n` itself is modified within the loop for digit separation.

Hope it helps! And if so, please l**eave your opinions**!! ^^

Answer (score -1):

I solved it!! It was such a stupid question (ಥ﹏ಥ) thank you coding people for not laughing at me.
I just had to put input n into another variable and then use that in the 2nd half.

```
n=int(input())
k=n
count=0
while n>0:
  count=count+1
  n=n//10

x=10**(count-1)
for a in range(1,count+1,1):
   y=int(k//x)
   k=k%x
   x=x/10

   print(y,end=" ")
```

Comment: If the input value is less than 1, this does not produce any output